# Cdn And Magento2

Tags: magento2, cdn

I have followed some tutorials to use cdn in magento2, but after making the settings, my site simply stopped working, and it does not load any more images, nothing else! I can not even roll back cdn settings through the admin panel anymore. How can I revert these settings?

Comment: Please check `core_config_table`

Comment: Thanks, the problem has been resolved by removing from the table core_config_table